# Nexus 5 does not see iPhone 5 configured as iBeacon

Tags: iphone, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I have configured an Iphone 5 to be an iBeacon transmitter following [this](https://passkit.com/configure-iphone-ibeacon-transmitter/) instructions.

Then I have installed [this](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK) application on my Nexus 5. But my Nexus is not able to see the iBeacon-iPhone device.. Do you have any idea why?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: what are you using to detect the iBeacon on the Nexus 5?

Comment: I have just installed [this](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK) Demo application downloaded from Estimote Android SDK, it should detect the iBeacons around..

Comment: Is your receiver configured to display beacons with unknown UUIDs? (That's possible on Android though not on iOS).  If not, is it configured to look for the precise UUID your iPhone is transmitting?  Is bluetooth turned on?

Comment: Agree with @ChrisStratton here.  Make sure your Nexus is looking for the specific UUID the iPhone is transmitting.  Alternatively, you can also use a sniffing device such as the Mac OS X hardware dev tool PacketSniffer to sniff the Bluetooth signal and check if you're transmitting a signal at all, or if you're transmitting the correct signal.

Answer (score 0):

The estimote demo application will look for estimote beacons only.
Download the RadiusNetworks iBeacon locate app on both phones.
On the iPhone, broadcast the beacon, and on the nexus, locate IBeacons.